# How to add string values to Pandas Dataframe within a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, data-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe `df_causation` which I have created as an empty dataframe with a corresponding column name.

```
df_causation = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Question'])
```

I have a `for` loop, in which for each iteration of the loop, I get a new string called `cause_str` like this:-

```
for i in range(len(X_test)):
   cause_str = hyp.join(f_imp) #cause_str is a new string obtained for each iteration
```

**(Ignore the method on how this is obtained, I just gave an example)**

I would like to append these new strings `(cause_str)` (all of them) **to each successive row** in my Pandas dataframe `df_causation`'s Question column. Any suitable way for doing this?

**EDIT: EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
df_causation.  **Causation**
   Row 0          cause_str from i = 0 th iteration in loop
   Row 1          cause_str from i = 1 th iteration in loop etc.
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a little example of the output you are looking for? I'm having a hard time getting the full picture of the issue.

Comment: Please find the expected output in the edit. Thanks @IvanLibedinsky

Comment: Alright, thanks. Now, what I think you should do is to make `cause_str` a list and then simply define df_causation['Question'] = cause_str. If the length is correct, then each index-value of the `list` will match the row in the dataframe.

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs? As @CeliusStingher said, it seems like all you need is column assignment, right?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC correctly, this should work:

```
dfd['**Causation**'] = df['df_causation.'].apply(lambda x: f'cause str from i = {x.split(" ")[1]} th iteration in loop')                                                             

df3                                                                                                                                                                                   

  df_causation.                              **Causation**
0         Row 0  cause str from i = 0 th iteration in loop
1         Row 1  cause str from i = 1 th iteration in loop
```